# Unknown service: 'glue'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I am Using boto3 1.26.155 version and trying to connect the client for 'glue'.But it says its not available in the list of services.

```
Unknown service: 'glue'. Valid service names are: acm, apigateway, application-autoscaling, appstream, athena, autoscaling, batch, budgets, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, codepipeline, codestar, cognito-identity, cognito-idp, cognito-sync, config, cur, datapipeline, dax, devicefarm, directconnect, discovery, dms, ds, dynamodb, dynamodbstreams, ec2, ecr, ecs, efs, elasticache, elasticbeanstalk, elastictranscoder, elb, elbv2, emr, es, events, firehose, gamelift, glacier, greengrass, health, iam, importexport, inspector, iot, iot-data, kinesis, kinesisanalytics, kms, lambda, lex-models, lex-runtime, lightsail, logs, machinelearning, marketplace-entitlement, marketplacecommerceanalytics, meteringmarketplace, mturk, opsworks, opsworkscm, organizations, pinpoint, polly, rds, redshift, rekognition, resourcegroupstaggingapi, route53, route53domains, s3, sdb, servicecatalog, ses, shield, sms, snowball, sns, sqs, ssm, stepfunctions, storagegateway, sts, support, swf, waf, waf-regional, workdocs, workspaces, xray
```

I tried upgrading and downgrading  boto3 version but that didn't help.

Comment: What [mcve] is producing that output? What does `boto3.__version__` show? What region and partition are you in? There are A LOT of services missing in that list.

Comment: Please show us enough code so that we can attempt to reproduce your error.

Comment: @luk2302 
crawler = boto3.client('glue', region_name='us-east-1')
boto3 version 1.26.155
botocore version 1.29.155

Comment: crawler = boto3.client('glue', region_name='us-east-1')

throwing error in this line that the service is not available @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Please go into Python command-line and run `import boto3` followed by `boto3.__version__` -- it will show the _actual_ version that is being run. It does _not_ show the botocore version number, so where ever you are getting the above version information is from somewhere different.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you where right it was taking the wrong version while running had to delete the old packages and reinstall with the latest one. Thankyou so much .

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by running an old version of boto3.

To determine the *actual* version of boto3 being used, run this program:

```py
import boto3

print(boto3.__version__)
```

If it doesn't match the version you have installed, hunt around for some old packages that might be hanging around.